# How do I make text wrap around an image without leaving whitespace or linebreaks?

Tags: html, css

I want to have text wrap around an image (which I achieved) and when a line breaks not to have whitespace around the image.
[image]

```html
<div id="container1">
  <div id="container2" style="width: 300px">
    <font color="black">
       <h1 class="customfonter">Title</h1>
       <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/530x400" width="34%" height="auto" style="float: left; margin-right:1%;margin-top:1%;">
    <pre style="width: auto;white-space: pre-wrap;word-wrap: break-word;">Randomtext Randomtext Randomtext Randomtext Randomtext Randomtext Randomtext Randomtext Randomtext Randomtext Randomtext Randomtext Randomtext Randomtext Randomtext Randomtext Randomtext Randomtext  <a id="link" href="#">more</a></pre>
    </font>
  </div>
<div>
```

Comment: What's the expected output? I think that in your case, the font size is exceeding the white space of 1-2 pixels, so it can't fit even if at first glance it looks like it can fit. Try fidding with line-height

Comment: Your initial sample had a `<pre>`, but were removed by a user. Should it be with a `<pre>`... and if, you have to add it back.

Comment: @CristianTraìna `line-height` isn't universal and the picture is always 34% of the containers width, so when the width changes so does the picture width and then I have the same problem.

Comment: @LGSon I've added it back.

Comment: The only 2 things I can see could work is, given you commented you don't want to use media query's, either a script or viewport units for `width/line-height/font`.

Comment: Or add padding or margin around the right side and bottom of the image to make it look equal at all times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find the solution I was looking for, so I settled with using `margin-bottom` to make sure no text got under the picture.

The script I made to automatically change the height of the bottom margin with the `HTML` from my question:

```js
setInterval(refresh, 1000/30);
function refresh() {
   ih = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;
   ph = document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;
   document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].style.marginBottom = `${Math.abs(ph - ih)}px`;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1">
  <div id="container2" style="width: 300px">
    <font color="black">
       <h1 class="customfonter">Title</h1>
       <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/530x400" width="34%" height="auto" style="float: left; margin-right:1%;margin-top:1%;">
    <pre style="width: auto;white-space: pre-wrap;word-wrap: break-word;">Randomtext Randomtext Randomtext Randomtext Randomtext Randomtext Randomtext Randomtext Randomtext Randomtext Randomtext Randomtext Randomtext Randomtext Randomtext Randomtext Randomtext Randomtext  <a id="link" href="#">more</a></pre>
    </font>
  </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to play with **line-height** for your text to best fit or set a **margin-right** for your image to make same 'whitespace' between text and image

Comment: As I've said : line-height isn't universal and the picture is always 34% of the containers width, so when the width changes so does the picture width and then I have the same problem. And  my problem is the whitespace on the BOTTOM of the image (not on the sides).

Comment: so when it's fluid use calc() function (also using % units) for line-height to match this too elements

Comment: Where would I get the first value from? The width is 34% and height is `auto`. So I cant get the height value.